# substitutability of super and this

Tags: java, inner-classes

I've read about the substitutability of `super` and `this` in Java, so that a reference to `super` is legal in the same places where `this` is legal in the superclass (with the exception of the code of class Object, in which super cannot appear). When I put this to the test it seems to fail as shown in the following example:

```
class OuterSuper {
  public int oneNumber() { return 5; }
  class Inners {}
  int i1 = OuterSuper.this.oneNumber();
  OuterSuper.Inners si1 = OuterSuper.this.new Inners();
}
class Outer extends OuterSuper {
  class Inner {
    int i1 = Outer.this.oneNumber();
    int i2 = Outer.super.oneNumber();
    OuterSuper.Inners si1 = Outer.this.new Inners();
    OuterSuper.Inners si2 = Outer.super.new Inners();
  }
}
```

The compiler balks at the last declaration, of member si2. In this example, I am able to write declarations for int i1 and i2 and it is just like the specification says, I can replace whatever I pass to super, to this in the superclass. For the inner class I am stuck and have to use this. Is this this a different this? I'm writing "Outer.this" and "Outer.super" in both instances...

I would like to share that I am using javac (the commandline JDK from Oracle 1.6) and NetBeans. The error I get from javac is:

```
Exe.java:32: <identifier> expected
        OuterSuper.Inners si2 = Outer.super.new Inners();
                                            ^
Exe.java:32: invalid method declaration; return type required
        OuterSuper.Inners si2 = Outer.super.new Inners();
                                                ^
2 errors
```

Comment: My compiler has no issues with your code. What the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: The code compiles perfectly in eclipse with java 6. Until you provide more info including the error message, I vote for closing this question

Comment: @AdelBoutros I have provided the information you requested, and I would ask you not to vote to close this question!

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the exact code. As Abel states, it compiles for me in Eclipse.

Comment: @JohnB Mishax is right. It compiles in Eclipse, but `does not compile on the command line with javac` (I tried OpenJDK 1.6.0_22 and JDK 1.7.0_09)

Comment: @JohnB, I have double checked. Yes, the code is as shown above, and when I use javac this is the result I get. I do not understand why so many people are referring to Eclipse? According to the Java Language Specification, javac is the reference implementation of the compiler? This is not the first time I've had an issue with javac that could not be reproduced in Eclipse or IntelliJ, though.

Comment: Mishax, Eclipse helps javac under the hood. That is why sometimes things can compile in Eclipse but not on the command line. I had a similar problem with generics. Looking up on the net, I found the answer. Hope you can do the same :)

Comment: @AdelBoutros Eclipse has its own compiler. What do you mean by "Eclipse helps javac under the hood"? And what was the problem you had with generics?

Comment: If you have this syntax: `Gen1<Gen2<T>> getMe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here are my two-cents. I was under the impression that `super` could only be used in a class to reference its own base class. I didn't think it was allowed to reference another class' `super` even given the inner class relationship. This is because no class other that the class itself should be able to bypass method overriding.

So, according to the Java Specification:

> It is a compile-time error if the current class is not an inner class of class T or T itself

Given this, your code should compile.

Comment: Since according to your reasoning it should compile, and in Eclipse it does compile, would you consider this is a bug in javac? What does one do in this situation?

Comment: Since there should never be a reason to use `super` outside the class to which it is referring, don't use it. Needing to call `super` from an inner class is an edge case which I have never come across. I know this is not a good answer that is why I am following your post to see if anyone else comes up with something better.

Comment: Well, what if you had an OuterSuper.Inner and an Outer.Inner and wanted to distinguish between the two, in code from Outer.Inner? OuterSuper.this would not be right, so you would need Outer.super.new Inner() in that case I think.. ?

Comment: If you have two classes that inherit from each other that each have a non-private inner class with the same name, you REALLY need to refactor things. Also, the `super` there is to reference the `super` instance. You could create an instance of a super inner class with `new OuterSuper.Inner()` which would use the `this` instance of `Outer` which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use `Outer` instead of `OuterSuper` on those two lines:

```
class Outer extends OuterSuper {
  class Inner {
    int i1 = Outer.this.oneNumber();
    int i2 = Outer.super.oneNumber();
    Outer.Inners si1 = Outer.this.new Inners();
    Outer.Inners si2 = Outer.super.new Inners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have got confused by the glitch the past two days with spaces in the code formatting. The errors javac was showing were actually to the right of the = operator, not all the way to the left, as it appeared since these spaces were suppressed due to the glitch. Anyway thanks for your tip, but I tried it and it didn't solve the problem for javac.

Answer (score 0):

> a reference to super in a class is equivalent to the reference to this in a superclass

The statement is completely incorrect. super.x() always refers to the base class's implementation of x(), whereas this.x() in the superclass may refer to an override of x() in the derived class, if there is one.

Comment: indeed, that is not correct. I meant to express that it is legal to use super in the same places where this can be used (with the exception of in the code of Object, of course). I'll edit the post.